# Accessing $scope in .animation using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-animate

I have a slideshow directive (self-made) which is adjustable - some variables change, for instance, I have a scope variable containing these settings:

```
{
 animationSpeed : 30,
 transitionTime : 1.5
}
```

As animation library I use greensock (GSAP) and the animations are defined as follows :

```
ModuleSlideshow.animation('.slide-left-animation', ['$window',function ($window) {
    "use strict";

    var getScope = function(e){
        var scope = angular.element(e).scope();
        if(scope){ scope = scope.$parent; }
        if(scope){ scope = scope.$parent; }
        return scope;
    };

    return {
        enter: function (element, done) {
            TweenMax.fromTo(element, getScope(element).animationSpeed, {left: -$window.innerWidth, ease : Power4.easeInOut}, {left: 0, ease: Power4.easeInOut, onComplete: done});
        },

        leave: function (element, done) {
            TweenMax.to(element,getScope(element).animationSpeed,{left : $window.innerWidth,ease : Power4.easeInOut, onComplete: done});
        }
    };
}]);
```

As you can see there I try to grab the scope with the element I get (the element is a `.slide` div, and I go up to the parent twice (to grab correct variables).

This works sometimes, but sometimes not, and I get some JavaScript error saying that `"cannot read property $parent of null"`. I tried to inject `$scope` directly, but this doesn't seem to work. How would you access scope in my case? Should I change the way I setup the animation?

Comment: why do you have scope in `...'$window','$scope',functio...`? does it need to be in there at all? though you should only need it in `...function ($window,$scope)...`

Comment: I edited my code, now it is like it should be. This syntax is array syntax. It is necessary for minification

Comment: cool, you'll still need to put the `$scope` in to be used for each method. I think you can leave it in the `function($scope){...`

Comment: i don't understand...

Comment: So right you need `$scope` & `$window` right? so you need them as services in your `function()` so either make a load of functions in this module with the specific services or add your services in the 1st function. tbh im not sure wich will work or maybe they both will but give it a shot and see if it works.

Comment: Well, i cannot inject $scope in .animation (don't know why it is like that) if i try with this code : `.animation('.slide-down-animation',function($window,$scope) { `                                                                                           it throws me   `"Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- .slide-left-animation-animation" `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88226/discussion-between-romain-ensminger-and-joe-lloyd).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem almost exactly like yours where I needed to access the element's scope. It seemed using `element.scope()` will be fine but will break especially if you intend to use `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`, which is recommended in Angular apps for performance. Although you lose access to the scope of the element when you turn off Debug Info, you still do have access to the element's controller via `data()`.

Perhaps if you refactor your code to utilize a controller for your directive, you'll be able to access the scope variable you need.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
  }])
  .controller('myDirectiveCtrl', function ($scope, $el) {
    this.animationSpeed = $scope.animationSpeed;
  })
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        animationSpeed: '='
      },
      controller: 'myDirectiveCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
  })
  .animation('.my-directive', function () {
    return {
      addClass: function (element, className, done) {
        var vm = element.data().$myDirectiveController;
        console.log(vm.animationSpeed, className);
      },
      removeClass: function (element, className, done) {
        var vm = element.data().$myDirectiveController;
        console.log(vm.animationSpeed, className);
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the one above; I could not inject scope into the directive controller. I created a service instead to communicate like so and it works well and I can keep the them ..

```
angular
        .module('App')
        .service('SliderService', function (){
            return {
                direction: null
            };
        });
     angular
        .module("App")
        .directive('slider',slider);

     slider.$inject = ['SliderService'];

        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { var unbindWatch =  scope.$watch('direction', function () { SliderService.direction = scope.direction });
```

Remember to kill watches and timers with scope.

```
scope.$on('destroy',function () { unbindWatch() }) }
```

Then for the animation use the following

```
angular
    .module("App")
    .animation('.slide-animation', slideAnimation);
slideAnimation.$inject  =['SliderService'];
function slideAnimation ( SliderService) {
    return {
        beforeAddClass: function (element, className, done) {
            if (className == 'ng-hide' && SliderService.direction) { ... }
        }
    }
```